# kubevirt had volume node affinity conflict

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to set up kubevirt following https://kubevirt.io/2019/How-To-Import-VM-into-Kubevirt.html and https://github.com/kubevirt/containerized-data-importer

The instructions are not fully complete so I had to manually create PV
[image]

The error I get is

```
0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
```

[image]

I have tried this https://www.datree.io/resources/kubernetes-troubleshooting-fixing-persistentvolumeclaims-error#anchor0 but still same issue

Comment: Is your issue resolved?if yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as a solution and accept it for helping other community members.